# Simple Quadratic function

Tags: quadratics

If we say that the minimum of a quadratic function is   **-3**

And the sum of its zeros/roots is  **2**

And I want to find the value of  **F(1)**

How do I write down the given here in a more applicable form to the question?

Comment: How could the quadratic be written in order to make the minimum value clear ? (hint it will also make the $x$ value where the minimum occurs clear) ... ping me when you have an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extremum of a quadratic function happens at the half-sum of its roots (whether real of complex), thus at $x=1$, so $F(1)=-3$.

Note this function is equal to
$$F(x)=a(x-1)^2-3 \quad\text{for some} \,a\in\mathbf R.$$